# Python class method not running

Tags: python, class

I'm new to Python. I'm confused as to why the method innerMethod in the code below does not run when being called from another method in the class or from the instantiated object. I don't get an error but the print command is not called.

```
# create a class
class Room:
    length = 0.0
    breadth = 0.0

    # method to calculate area
    def calculate_area(self):
         print("Area of Room =", self.length * self.breadth)
         self.innerMethod

     def innerMethod():
         print("testing")

# create object of Room class
study_room = Room()

# assign values to all the attributes 
study_room.length = 42.5
study_room.breadth = 30.8

# access method inside class
study_room.calculate_area()
```

Comment: As usual I figured it out right after I posted this...sigh.

Comment: You forgot the `()`.

Comment: You also forgot the `self` parameter for the innerMethod.

Comment: If you've already solved it, and you know it's a syntax issue, why not just delete it? Nobody is going to stumble across this post in their search for a specific issue, so it doesn't add value to a Q&A

Comment: Unrelated to the specific problem... You should probably familiarise yourself with the concepts of class and instance variables. In your code both *length* and *breadth* are class variables. Instance variables would be more appropriate